# expressing value of textbox in xpath?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xpath

how can  i express the value of a textbox in xpath ?

the text that was just typed into the textbox.

so if i type apple inside a textbox, i need to output the value of this in xpath.

Answer (score 0):

First off, if you're doing this more than once or twice, the overhead of doing the xpath repeatedly is probably not desirable.

```
document.evaluate("id('textareaid')", document, null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE,null).stringValue;`
```

will return the text from inside the textarea, but not the text input afterwards.

What you want is the value *property* not the value *attribute*. xpath can only see the attribute, not the property.

So... to get the value of the textarea input, you need:

```
var mytextarea = document.evaluate("id('textareaid')", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE,null).singleNodeValue;

var text = mytextarea.value;
```

Note: document.getElementById() is much better than an xpath that only searches by id. I assume your case is more complicated so I've left the xpath structure in place.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript for more detail.

Comment: so how to get the value property ?

Comment: See the second block of code. `mytextarea.value` is the value property. `mytextarea.getAttribute('value')` would be the value attribute. You want the property.